# Forgetful functor from Magma to Set

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, forgetful-functors

I'm trying to do an exercise on adjoints, where one of the questions asks to prove that the forgetful functor $U: \mathsf{Magma} \rightarrow  \mathsf{Set}$ has a left adjoint.

Is there a way of proving this, assuming that both Magma and Set are categories?

Comment: Do you know *how* are $\mathsf{Magma}$ and $\mathsf{Set}$ defined? There is hardly anything to be done if one does not know what the terms *mean*.

Comment: Not quite. I'd advise you to read carefully the definition of category; and of the categories of sets and magmas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In general, for any algebraic theory $\mathcal A$ (that is magmas, monoids, groups, etc.. ) their is an adjunction
$$U:\mathcal A \to \mathcal Set$$
$$F:\mathcal Set\to\mathcal A$$
with right adjoint given by a forgetful functor $U$ and left adjoint given by the free algebra functor $F$. Formally, a free algebra on a set $X$ is defined by the left adjoint as $F(X)$. But intuitively, a free algebra on a set $X$ is smallest algebra containing $X$ which is "freely" generated by the terms of the algebra.

So to get the left adjoint for the theory of magmas, you need to ask yourself what is a free magma generated by a set.

Hint:

> A free monoid on a set $X$ is the monoid of words with alphabet $X$. If you remove associativity and the identity, you get trees with $X$-labelled leaves. For example, if $X=\{a,b,c\}$, then the underlying set of the free magma on $X$ is given the set of terms $$U_{\text{Magma}}(F_{\text{Magma}}(X))=\{a,b,c,\mu(a,c),\mu(a,\mu(\mu(a,b),c)),\ldots etc.\}$$

Comment: In a free magma, you would have to remove associatvity, identity and commutativity?

Comment: you do not, in general, have commutativity, but you would indeed have to "remove" identity and associativity from a monoid to get a magma

Comment: So the tree is the free magma?

Comment: it is not really just one tree. the trees are $n$-ary and represent the (parenthetizations of) products of magma elements, and the arity of the tree is the arity of the magma operation. usually it is 2, so you get binary trees

Comment: Yes. Formally, a free algebra is characterized by the left adjoint. But intuitively, a free algebra on a set $X$ is smallest algebra containing $X$ which is "freely" generated by the terms of the algebra. So since a free magma only has an operation $\mu:M\times M\to M$, then for example, the free magma on $X=\{x_0,x_1,x_2\}$ has terms $x_0,x_1,x_2,\mu(x_0,x_2),\mu(x_0,\mu(\mu(x_0,x_1),x_2)),\ldots$ etc. That is, all binary trees with $X$-labelled leaves.

Answer (score 0):

Magmas are algebraic structures, and, as such, enjoy the existence of *free* objects. Do you see why this implies the existence of a particular left adjoint?